# Ethereum : How to auto-split an ETH transaction into 2 other transactions

Tags: transactions, ethereum, solidity, fallback, smartcontracts

Let's say I have a shared wallet where ethers are collected for me and my brother. We share 50% each other of this wallet.

if one ETH transaction comes to this wallet, is there an automated way to auto send received ethers to my personal wallet and to my brother's one, without us to do anything special?

Can it be done through a special smartcontract (with fallback) or any other way?

Comment: At least, what can be done is to do the auto-send to my brother of its 50% share, and I'm keeping this common wallet as mine. So it reduces transaction and fees. Any idea?

Comment: Yes, this is straightforward. Where's your code so far, and where did you get stuck?

Comment: I don't have any code yet since I wish to know if that is possible to be done first, and how

Comment: I think this type of question is generally off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: This is a programmer's question: Not off-topic.  fallback is a part of the solidity language (ETH smart contract). I would be glad if someone has a bit of code to handle this. thanks

Comment: Some resources that might answer your question: https://github.com/0xcaff/splitter-contract https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/25499/can-an-ethereum-payment-be-split-90-10-between-two-wallets

Comment: The reason it's off-topic is because it's a "please write code for me" type of question. It doesn't seem like you've tried anything yet.

Comment: Thanks for the links, they will help me to continue

Answer (score 2):

You can deploy this contract (don't forget change addresses)

When someone sends you ethers, he needs to put 100000 gas, this additional gas needs to send 2 transactions: for you and your bro

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.25;
contract Split {
    address public constant MY_ADDRESS = 0x5Ac652E32b8064000a4ab34aF0AE24E4966E309E;
    address public constant BRO_ADDRESS = 0x43CcDF0774813B6E14E64b18b34dE438B039663C;

    function () external payable {
        if (msg.value > 0) {
            // msg.value - received ethers
            MY_ADDRESS.transfer(msg.value / 2);
            // address(this).balance - contract balance after transaction to MY_ADDRESS (half of received ethers)  
            BRO_ADDRESS.transfer(address(this).balance);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to pass in recipient address and allow manager to change commission address? I’m looking to send payments where I take a 2% commission

Answer (score -1):

Yes. Take a look at Open Zeppelin split payment:
https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity/blob/master/contracts/payment/SplitPayment.sol

That uses claims, but you could do something similar and use a smart contract fallback to automate this.